# How to merge realtime example ,scaleengine and svgmap into one class

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am trying to use realtime example from qwt to provide for zoomer and svgmap example to provide panner ,Also I want to use custom transform ability.

I am trying to make single header and single class which inherits from the 3 classes But errors occur because each plotting class in the examples inherits from qwtplot and has Qobject macro.
how I can make this single class which inherits interface of the other 3 classes,Then in the constructor how can I merge the 3 constructors??

Comment: It is not possible to inherit multiple `QObject` derived classes. If you want to inherit multiple classes make sure the first one is has meta data, moc ignores others. `class MeAndTheBoys : public QObjectDerivedMe, public TheBoy, public TheOtherBoys ...`. If others also have metadata (constains Q_OBJECT or Q_GADGET), then only option is composition or aggregation. There is also a `Q_INTERFACES` macro, but it not as much useful as it seems.

Comment: Please put links for examples you mention?

Comment: thanks for ur comment. I just gave up on multiple inheritance and modified one class to accomodate the other one.